# Communication between two adapters

Tags: java, android

I am looking solution for implementation in few words, how to react on event in adapter A that happen in adapter B. More clearly this looks on images.

I have two tabs, result of search and favorites, on first I have list of images, when I press the favorite icon, it will be saved to bookmarks, then I want to remove image by pressing the icon, all is good, but on tab of results this image still will be marked like favorite image.

Choose as favourite

[image: first]

If you press the button the image will be removed from the favorites, but on the previous tab will mark it as a favorite, like above.

[image: second]

How can I implement something like the communication between two adapters or something similar, any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, in **Adapter B** calling `findFragmentByTag` from `Context`, get fragment instance, going to the **Adapter A**, call the appropriate method. What it looks like in the code:

*Adapter B*

```
  private void changeIconOnResults(int position){
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;
    resultFragment = (ResultOfSearch)(activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(activity.pagerAdapter.getTag(0)));
    resultFragment.adapter.removeSavedUrl(pathList.get(position),false);
}
```

*Adapter A*

```
 public void removeSavedUrl(String url,boolean isInternalAccess){
    savedURLs.remove(url);//remove from itemList
    if(!isInternalAccess) {
        for (int i = 0; i <imageList.size() ; i++) {
            if(TextUtils.equals(imageList.get(i).getLink(),url)) {
                imageList.get(i).setIsFavourite(false);//uncheck from pojo
                this.notifyItemChanged(i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Adapter A when event happen then [broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) the event and Adapter B will receive the broadcast to take some action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't figure out how to get access to current ViewHolder to change icon. I can get access from adapter B to adapter A without broadcast receiver, but that's not what I need.